# Check whether or not a certain extension is installed in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I'm working on a Salesforce Application. The application contains some custom objects, one of which is Project. I have created a Visualforce page to manage these projects. We are also developing an extension. In the extension a new custom field is added to the Project object. 
In the original package I want to change the visualforce page to show whether the value of that field (if the extension is installed). So I need to check if the extension is intalled, and if so, display a field from that extension.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I ended up using was to create an interface in the base class with a default implementation that doesn't do much. Then I created a custom setting in which another class name that implements that interface should be entered. Also in the base class I created a Factory that can be used to get the implementation of the interface. I used [this guide](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2012/05/dynamic-apex-class-instantiation-in-summer-12.html) as a basis.

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off asking same question at the [Salesforce-dedicated Stack site](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/). Seems like there are many members who build managed packages.

I'd try some dynamic Apex (like [describe methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm)) to check if the object & field exists.

For example if you have installed a Chatter Unfollow app from AppExchange and want to rely on its' objects:

```
String objectName = 'chttrunfollow__UnfollowRule__c';
String fieldName = 'chttrunfollow__Active__c';

Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
Schema.SObjectType t = gd.get(objectName);
if(t != null) {
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult sobjectDescribe = t.getDescribe();
    System.debug(sobjectDescribe.isAccessible());

    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fields = sobjectDescribe.fields.getMap();
    if(fields != null && fields.get(fieldName) != null && fields.get(fieldName).getDescribe().isAccessible()) {
        System.debug('Show it!');
    }
} else {
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'Not found');
}
```

It can be a quite expensive operation so you'd probably want to cache the results somewhere (custom setting?).

There's a `System.requestVersion()` call but I think it returns only "your" current version (can't use it to ask for what else was installed in given org). if you use licenses - `UserInfo.isCurrentUserLicensed('namespace')` might be worth checking?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've found another solution to my problem, using Reflection to implement an interface defined in the base class.

Comment: Cool trick as well! Please make it a full answer & accept it :) I must have had a brainfart moment... you could also query `ApexClass` table... eh.